# Supressing Sonar issues on PL/SQL code

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarlint

How to suppress Sonar warning from PL/SQL inline code? For Java its simple, by using

```java
//NOSONAR
```

Will

```sql
--NOSONAR
```

work on PL/SQL Code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NOSONAR is [supported in version 2.9](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLSQL-506) of SonarPLSQL. There's also [a rule to track usages of NOSONAR](https://rules.sonarsource.com/plsql/RSPEC-1291).

Comment: Your second link is broken. I couldn't easily find a replacement.